# Anti Forgery Token Best Practice

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cors, authorization, antiforgerytoken

I am using **asp.net core Rest API**. I set **JWT** token in cookie, but there is a threat of **CSRF**. I searched and found that anti forgery token should be stored as cookie. But I have question here:

1. Is it still threat isn't it ? because if somebody make request from other domain, the anti forgery token cookie will still be included in request.
2. Why should I use anti forgery token stored in cookie when I already using authorization cookie ? If somebody will manage to send me the auth cookie it will handle to send me anti forgery token too.
3. Should I store forgery token in localStorage in front-app and send it as request header ?
4. How often should I refresh *anti forgery token* ?
5. If I use **CORS**, How will someone be able to use **CSRF** attack against me ? `backend` will refuse this kind requests right ? So Why should I use anti forgery token ?

Comment: This is 5 questions into one. Not well suited for Stack Overflow...